# MVC design pattern with cocos2dx and cpp

Tags: c++, asp.net-mvc, cocos2d-x

I'm working with cocos2dx on Xcode, I have a question about cpp MVC design pattern.

when my model value changes internally, should I pass the changed value with the event or should i inform the view and let the view do the request for those values through the controller?

I'm asking is this appropriate to used in MVC design pattern.

I create my controller (which inherits from ViewDelegate and Scene) using the static Method to create it. Within the init method in controller, I used View's static method to create instance. I Then set delegate(ViewDelegate*) and pass a reference of Controller. This way the view can use the ViewDelegate reference to access the methods declared as a virtual methods in ViewDelegate. Controller can access View with its instance, which was created before.

On the other side , I create my model as a singleton. Used it in side of my controller and when the value in model changes internally, I use event dispatcher to dispatch a Event telling the View it has changed.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Are you asking if what you are doing is correct? or is something broken, and you're looking for help to fix it?

Comment: Passing data with the event may make the connection more stronger, and notify only will make the code more complex. Which one you would prefer to choose?